# NullPointerException - label.settext in start method javafx

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, scenebuilder, settext

I am new to javafx and scenebuilder but got interested after a project in school.

I am trying to write an application where the user login with their account and gets to the main window.

In the main window I want a label to show who the account belongs to (username used to login).

I have created a context class where I store the username used to login.

In the start method in the controller class for the main window I try use settext(Context.username) but end up with a nullpointerexception. When I print out Context.username I get the correct value and if I bind the settext method to a button everything works just fine.

My guess is that I try to use the settext before the label is loaded from the FXML-file.

I've looked around online for hours but can't find a solution to my problem.

Please help.

Below is the method calling the second controller-class.

```
@FXML
    private  TextField userName_txt;

    @FXML
    private  PasswordField password_txt;    

@FXML
    public void checkLogin(ActionEvent event){
        this.username = userName_txt.getText();
        this.password = password_txt.getText();
        Context.username = username;
        Context.password = password;

        try {

            System.out.println("running check login with: " + username + " " + password);
            if(dbq.checkLogin(username, password)) {

                System.out.println("Successful login");
                loginMessage_txt.setText("Successful login!");
                loginMessage_txt.setFill(Color.GREEN);

                Controller2 controller2 = new Controller2();
                controller2.start(stage);

            }else {

                    System.out.println("Wrong password or username");
            loginMessage_txt.setText("Wrong password or username!");
            loginMessage_txt.setFill(Color.RED);

        }
    }catch(Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

Below is the start method for the second controller class (main).

```
public class Controller2 extends Application{

private DatabaseQueries dbq = new DatabaseQueries();

@FXML
private Label accountBelongsTo_lbl;    

@Override
    public void start(Stage mainStage) {

    System.out.println("Running Controller2.start");

    try {

        Database db = new Database();

        db.openConnection("root", "xxxxx");

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
        Context.root = loader.load();           


        // root2.getChildrenUnmodifiable();

        Scene scene = new Scene(Context.root);          

        System.out.println("Pre new scene: " + Context.stage.toString());

        Context.stage.setScene(scene);
        Context.stage.show();
        Context.stage.centerOnScreen();

        System.out.println("Post new scene: " + Context.stage.toString());
        System.out.println("username is: " + Context.username);

        accountBelongsTo_lbl.setText("Context.username");

}catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Exception in start (startmainstage)");
        }
    }
```

I've also tried loading the FXML-file in .init() method and the settext in main but the same problem occur.

Below is a draft from the FXML-file for the controller2-class (main).

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="ap_main" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="1000.0" style="-fx-background-color: White;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller2">
   <Label fx:id="accountBelongsTo_lbl" layoutX="952.0" layoutY="19.0" text="Label" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="30.0">
         <font>
            <Font size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
```

Below is the print-outs and stack trace.

```
Connecting to database...
Connected to database!
Pre new scene: javafx.stage.Stage@725707ff
post new scene: javafx.stage.Stage@725707ff
running check login with: xxxxx 123456
Connecting to database...
Connected to database!
Successful login
Database connection closed.
Running Controller2.start
Connecting to database...
Connected to database!
Pre new scene: javafx.stage.Stage@725707ff
Post new scene: javafx.stage.Stage@725707ff
java.lang.NullPointerExceptionusername is: xxxxx
at application.Controller2.start(Controller2.java:146)
at application.Controller.checkLogin(Controller.java:81)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
```

Code works just fine without settext(); method.

Please let me know if you need anything else from me, any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: "In the start method in the controller class...". Controllers don't have `start()` methods. `Application` classes have `start()` methods.

Comment: Thats right, I think I mixed it up since it extends Application. Thank you.